# time command - output to a file

Tags: macos, mac, bash, terminal.app

comamnd line:

```
time myprocess
```

outputs its results:

```
OUTPUT FROM MY PROCESS

real    0m1.954s
user    0m0.086s
sys     0m0.052s
```

But if I do

```
time myprocess > outputfile.txt
```

my outputFiel.txt will include only the output from my process. Not the time results.

How do I output everything into my file, including the output from "time"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parentheses to format the command as one block.

`(time myprocess) &> outputfile.txt`

[Bash Redirection](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections)